# What do "project references" do in Visual Studio 2017 with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio, C# project references are very straightforward. If you add a project reference to a consuming project ("ProjectA") pointing to producing project ("ProjectB"), the consuming project can use the namespaces and classes from that ProjectB.

In C++, dependencies are a bit more complicated.  We have 3 major variables that ProjectA needs from ProjectB in order to consume it.

1. Include directories
2. Lib directories
3. Libs for linking

This is a bit oversimplified, but it demonstrates the point.

ProjectB is aware of it's own variables, so one would think that adding a reference from ProjectA to ProjectB would somehow trigger Visual Studio to transmit these variables to ProjectA, perhaps by updating the corresponding fields in the `ProjectA.vcxproj`.

None of this seems to happen when we do "Add Project Reference", and everyone I talk to uses relative paths and props files to handle dependencies manually.

Conversely, in cmake, `target_link_libraries(consumer producer)` propagates everything (includes/libs/etc) from the producer up to the consumer as expected.

Thus, it is not clear to me what the purpose of "project references" are in Visual Studio for C++. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You will not get include directories nor lib directories for linking by using project references. The two big things you get are 1) project linking 2) implicit build order

Comment: By project linking, do you mean it's just the list of library filenames passed with `-lsomelib`?

Comment: By that I mean you don't need to go into `Additional Dependencies` and enumerate other `.lib` files, they will automatically be linked by the consuming project

Comment: And note that with MSVC it is often more straightforward to use "#pragma comment(lib, "...") in the library header particularly if the library produces different names based on configuration options.

Comment: @CoryKramer if you post your response as an answer, i'll accept it.